# How to deal with pointers to dynamic memory being returned in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, return

I was wondering the protocol for dealing with memory leaks with pointers to dynamic memory being returned in C and C++. For example, strtok returns a char*. Presumably, the pointer that is returned must eventually be freed/deleted. I note that the [reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) doesn't even mention this. Is that because this is simply assumed? Also, how do you know whether to delete or free? Does one have to do research to find out what language each function was originally in, and then assume that all C programs use malloc/free and C++ uses new/delete?

Comment: The reason the reference page does not mention it is that it is not true.

Comment: I think it's important to note that "the reference page" is just *a* reference page and not the standard definition of the function. But in this case, it's right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

strtok does NOT return a pointer to a newly allocated memory, but rather a pointer to a memory location, which has been previously allocated.

Let's assume this:

```
char String[1024];
strcpy(String, "This is a string");
char *Ptr = strtok(String, " ");
```

Ptr will not point to a newly allocated memory location, but rather to the location of String (if my counting doesn't fail me right now), with the space getting replaced by a '\0'. (

From the reference:
This end of the token is automatically replaced by a null-character by the function, and the beginning of the token is returned by the function.

That also means, that if you were to print out 'String' again after strtok has done its work, it would only contain 'This', since the string is terminated after that.

As a rule of thumb, you are safe to say, that you only need to free/delete memory you've explicitly allocated yourself.

That means:

For each 'new' put a 'delete', and for each 'malloc' put a 'free' and you're good.

Comment: To expand on this, where library functions require you to free memory, they will tell you in their documentation, and whether they are C or C++ functions is the key to whether `delete` or `free` is required.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, of course you are correct. If stated explicitly, freeing the memory in question is of course necessary. Though usually that isn't done with delete/free, but rather a specialized 'free' function, which matches the 'construction call'.

Comment: Yep that can be the case as well, certainly in libraries other than the standard C library.

Comment: That's right, for example in WINAPI [`FormatMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351) used with `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`, they specify you'll have to free the memory with [`LocalFree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366730).

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` is a C function that returns a pointer to a perviously allocated memory; `strtok` itself doesn't allocate new memory.

If something is allocated with `malloc` it has to be freed with `free`; anything allocated with new must be `free`d with `delete`.

Best way to deal with memory allocation/deallocation in modern C++ is to use smart pointers. Take a look at `std::shared_ptr`/`std::unique_ptr` and don't use raw pointers unless you absolutely have to.

Also using `std::string` and `std::vector` will remove most of your raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The `strtok` function does not perform any memory allocation. It is performing its operations on the string pointer provided by you. By the time the function is called you should have already made your mind about whether to allocate the memory for the pointer on the heap or use automatic stack storage. You could have written:

```
char * p = "Testing - string";
char * p2 = strtok(p, "- ");
```

here p2 does not have to bee freed/deleted because it was allocated on the stack. But here

```
char * p = "Testing - stringh";
char * p2 = malloc(strlen(p));
p2 = strtok(p, "- ");
```

you have allocated storage for p2 on the heap, so after you have finished with it it has to be freed and set to null:

```
if(p2 != NULL) { 
     free(p2);
     p2 = NULL;
}
```

So if you have use new for heap allocation, you then use delete; if you used malloc/calloc, you should the use free.

Comment: You know, you're raising an interesting question with your answer. Technically, you're toying with a string in program code. (since 'p' hasn't been allocated in any way). Usually, these are 'const char's, meaning that they cannot be altered. I also believe, that if you called strtok on that function, you might well get your program to crash with a segmentation fault or something. Your second example will leave you with a memory leak (since you're overwriting the pointer to the allocated memory) and finally the last one will crash, because no memory has been allocated to 'p'.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean to free p2. Freeing p that was not heap-allocated leads to undefined behavior. Thank you for pointing at my mistake.